# Indexing into multidimensional array

Tags: julia

In Julia, is it possible to index into one array with another? I'm looking for something like this:

```
a = Array{Int8}(undef, 3, 3, 3)
b = [1,2,3]

a[b] = 12
```

But so far the only solution I can find is `a[b[1], b[2], b[3]] = 12`. Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the clean way of doing it. You use the `...` for passing a tuple as function arguments, as well. This is known as *splatting*.

```
a[b...]
```